# Is it possible to create a inheritance in schema definition in Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

Can I do the following in `mongoose`?

const s1 = new mongoose.Schema({
description: String,
hints: [String],
});

const s2 = new mongoose.Schema({
s1_reference: s1, //inherit from s1
something_else: [String],
});

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the term [Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments) over "inheritance".

The official documentation defines it as

> Subdocuments are documents embedded in other documents. In Mongoose, this means you can nest schemas in other schemas

Which I think is you are looking for. Also the example provided is excatly as you want, so, yes, you can use your code in Mongoose.

This is the example from the official docs:

```js
const childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

const parentSchema = new Schema({ child: childSchema });
```

So you can do:

```js
const s1 = new mongoose.Schema({ description: String, hints: [String] });

const s2 = new mongoose.Schema({ s1_reference: s1, something_else: [String] });
```

Where `childSchema` is `s1` and `parentSchema` is `s2`.